# Recommendation for Python

Tags: untagged

I am a 20+ career IT admin with barely any programming background (just academic) and finally have to face up to reality to train/learn some form of scripting language. It seems Python is a good choice for most the reviews I've read.

Can anyone suggest a site, be it subscription or not, that has a courses and/or how to's for seasoned professionals that you can think of? I do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Oreilly python books are good http://shop.oreilly.com/category/browse-subjects/programming/python.do

Answer (score 2):

Probably a good start here:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

I've been a professional Python developer for almost 8 years now.  Loving every second of it!  Previous to that I worked exclusively in C.